# How to make jquery script work for new generated form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have one script which display the form on click response

```
$(".table th .glyphicon-edit").one('click', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var sectionName = $(this).attr('data-sectioname');
        var courseId = $(this).attr('data-courseid');
        var sectionId = $(this).attr('data-sectionid');
    $.get('/edit_section', { section: sectionName, id: courseId, sectionid: sectionId}, function(response) {
        $this.closest('thead tr').after(response);
    });
 });
```

"edit_section" page

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/managecourse/162" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="edit" class="form-horizontal">
  <input name="_method" value="PUT" type="hidden">
  <input name="_token" value="duTA8TbvmYeJWUA21VTGqZYisQZu1ouuhvbXCouv" type="hidden">
  <input name="sectionid" value="1" type="hidden">
  <input name="courseid" value="162" type="hidden">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="section_name" class="col-md-4 control-label text-right">Name sectiton</label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <input class="form-control" name="section_name" value="Name_section" id="section_name" type="text">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-center">
   <input name="edit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

And then I have script to submit this form but it doesn't work

```
$('#edit').submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
    var sectionName = $('input#section_name').val();
    var sectionId = $('input[name=sectionid]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: '/managecourse/update',
        data: $('#edit').serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

It just display new page with json data but would like to display this data at the same page without reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate your submit method. it will work on dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on('submit','#edit',function(){
   // code
});
```

Comment: I edit my script and now it looks like this 
    $(document).on('submit','#edit',function(){
    $('#edit input[type=submit]').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var sectionName = $('input#section_name').val();
   var sectionId = $('input[name=sectionid]').val();
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: '/managecourse/update',
    data: $('#edit').serialize(),
    success:function(data){
     console.log(data);
    },
   });
  });
    });
But it still load new page

Comment: Found the problem I don't need put    
$('#edit input[type=submit]').submit(function(e)
inside
$(document).on('submit','#edit',function(){
Thanks for help!!!